# Where is the sdcard location in Android Device Manager for the Samsung NOTE 5

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

I installed a database on a Samsung Note 5 programmatically in this directory:

```
public static String dataPath = "/mnt/sdcard/mycompany/sms2email/data/";
```

I am using the Android Device Manager to go pull out the database file from my device and I cannot find the directory in ADM.  On a Nexus 7, the location seemed to be:

```
mnt/shell/emulated/0/
```

Where is this directory for the sdcard?

Comment: What do you mean with `sdcard` ?

Comment: I mean, I can find the directory on my phone using astro file manager in the sdcard, but cannot find it in ADM.

Comment: I found the directory under: /mnt/sdcard/ but ADM will not let me look in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Never hardcode the sd directory.  Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.  The location of the sdcard will differ between models extensively.

Comment: Thanks, will take your advice, but still did not answer my question - how to get to this directory with ADM.

Comment: How do you get to the sdcard using ADM.

Comment: That gives the location, but not where to find the directory in ADM.

Comment: If you're having problems using ADM, then use adb pull instead.

Comment: That's just unfortunate.  I'd like to be able to use the Graphical user interface.